# Problems with Win7 & Adobe Reader

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-reader

My operating system is Win 7 Pro

I have installed Adobe Reader 10.1 when that didn't work, I installed Adobe Reader from the website, latest version. That doesn't work either.

I use Microsoft Outlook for my email client

With Adobe Reader installed, when I get an email with a .pdf file attached, when I wish to read the file I double click on it only to be greeted with a panel on screen saying "Windows can't open this file"

If I save the file to the hard drive, open Adobe Reader and direct it to the saved file, then it will open with no problem.

If I go directly to the saved file on the hard drive via Windows Explorer and then double click on it to read, I get the panel up on screen again saying  "Windows can't open this file"

Has anyone else had trouble like this and if so, how do I rectify it please

Answer (score 3):

It might act so because  pdf extension is not associated with Adobe Reader. To do so: Right mouse click on pdf file, go to "Properties", and then in "General" tab in "Opens with" section press "Change..." button. Find Adobe Reader, and press "OK"(If there is no Adobe Reader in the list, press "Browse" and find "exe" file of Adobe Reader in directory you have installed. Also you can do this in "Control Panel>Default Programs>Associate a file type or protocol with a program", find pdf and associate it with Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

> Open cmd.exe
>
> either with start and typing it into search
>
> or
>
> pressing windows button on keyboard and "r" at the same time.

**2.**
type in CMD.exe and press enter.

**3.**
Copy and Paste this code into CMD and run it. This will re-associate all your pdf's with the default program.

change the 10.0 to whichever version you are using. (ex.: 15.0)

```
ftype AcroExch.Document="C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 10.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" "%1"
```